# String copy function returns no value strcpy while converting NSString to c string

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

`sipurl` and `regurl` are `NSString` which I get from `UItextField`

```
    const char *sipAddr = [sipUrl cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *regAddr = [regUrl cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *uname = [orgUsername cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *pword = [password cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //const char *pword = [password UTF8String];
    const char *realm = [realmStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //char *sipAddrArr=strdup(sipAddr);
    //char *regAddrArr=strdup(regAddr);
    //char *unamearr=strdup(uname);
    //char *pwordarrnew = strdup(pword);

    char sipAddrArr[[sipUrl length]];
    strcpy(sipAddrArr,sipAddr);

    char regAddrArr[[regUrl length]];
    strcpy(regAddrArr,regAddr);

    char unamearr[[orgUsername length]] ;
    strcpy(unamearr, uname);

    char pwordarrnew[[password length]];
    strcpy(pwordarrnew,pword);

    char realmchr[[realmStr length]];
    strcpy(realmchr,realm);
    char pwordarr1[] = {"10000"};
    printf("\nPassword value sent: %s",pword);
    printf("\nPassword value sent: %s",pwordarr1);
```

`pword` has value while trying to copy constant char to char I use strcpy function it returns no value for pword. The same code works fine when testing in simulator but doesn't work when connected to iOS phone.

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Like adding some `printf` statements at certain places to see what are the values in the variables at that point? If not, try it and check the value `pword` has at that point.

Comment: @kiner_shah yes pword has the value from textfield but when i try to copy the value of pword to pwordarrnew pwordarrnew has novalue when i try to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be the cause of your problem, but it is an error in your code:

You are taking an `NSString`, converting it into a UTF8 C-string, and then copying the C-string into a C-array sized according to the length of the `NSString`. This is wrong, the `NSString` and its UTF8 translation can be different lengths. You need to determine the length of the UTF8 string and allow for the end-of-string marker. For example:

```
char sipAddrArr[strlen(sipAddr)+1];
strcpy(sipAddrArr,sipAddr);
```

and similarly for the other arrays.

HTH

Comment: i tried ur method but still no change .when i use strcpy function there is no value in pwordarr only.all other arrays are having values but pwordarr has no value when i print it

Comment: You need to use the debugger (or print statements) to examine the variables and values, in particular check what `strlen` is returning, the memory pointed at by `sipAddr`, and that `password` isn't empty/null itself. You still need the changes above or you will get problems.

Comment: i used print statements to print the values of all variables..but only pwordarrnew has no value when i print it after using strcpy.

Comment: Fix your code to use `strlen` as above and then ask a new question showing the fixed code, the debug statements, and the output. Show the values of all the variables. Somebody might be able to help you.

Comment: i updated like what u said and i didnt properly initialize my NSString objects using mallaoc and init.but rit now i changed it and follwed ur suggestion of strlen..and its working now properly.than you so much for ur help..and suggestion of strlen.much appreciated..